# Display alert onclicking on browser close tab but at the same time onclicking browser reload/refresh button alert shouldn't be displayed in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

My requirement is to display an alert on clicking on close icon is browser with the message saying that "Do you want to close the tab? IF yes You will logout".

I have tried with the beforeunload broswer event. But this event is working commonly for forward, backward, reload and close tab. But i want to display the alert only on click on tab close and browser close click.

How to know user is clicking on forward, backward & reload  (buttons) and close tab?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My requirements: 1. display a warning alert when the user clicks on the browser's tab close icon. 2. Alert should have yes or no buttons. 3. at the same time when the user clicks on the reload button page should reload with an alert.